# Python: How can I apply the polyfit feature in 3D with 3 arrays x[], y[], z[]

Tags: python, plot, 3d, curve-fitting, coefficients

I have this 3 arrays with my data:

```
X=np.array(x)
Y=np.array(y)
Z=np.array(z)
```

I know how to plot my points, and how to aply the polyfit in 2D. How can I get the polyfit coefficients from my data in 3D? And can I plot my 3D fitting curve?

Comment: Hi, maybe add the code of how you implemented the 2D fit, that might help to understand better what you want to achieve in 3D :)

Comment: X=np.array(x)
Y=np.array(y)
Z=np.array(z)

fit = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)
print(fit)

With this I get the coefficients, for my fitting curve in 2D (X, Y):

[ 5.38757322e-02 -2.22148919e-01  1.77194190e+02]

I want to apply the same method to my 3D data (X, Y, Z), so I can obtain the coefficients and plot the mathematical function. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's possible using `np.polyfit()`, but I found a reference that could help [here](https://pingswept.org/2009/06/15/least-squares-fit-of-a-surface-to-a-3d-cloud-of-points-in-python-(with-ridiculous-application)/). It implements finding the coefficients as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# note I have changed the capital to lowercase since the rest of the code is that way
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)

degree = 3

# Set up the canonical least squares form
Ax = np.vander(x, degree)
Ay = np.vander(y, degree)
A = np.hstack((Ax, Ay))

# Solve for a least squares estimate
(coeffs, residuals, rank, sing_vals) = np.linalg.lstsq(A, z)

# Extract coefficients and create polynomials in x and y
xcoeffs = coeffs[0:degree]
ycoeffs = coeffs[degree:2 * degree]

fx = np.poly1d(xcoeffs)
fy = np.poly1d(ycoeffs)
```

I hope that what you were looking for, further explention about the calculations are in the link above.